# Using bump constraint for a PDA with AccountLoader

Tags: anchor, pda

According to the [Anchor Book](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_in_depth/PDAs.html) bump constraint can be specified for a PDA, so Anchor doesn't need to search for it:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ChangeUserName<'info> {
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"user-stats", user.key().as_ref()], bump = user_stats.bump)]
    pub user_stats: Account<'info, UserStats>,
}
```

But when I try to use the same approach with AccountLoader:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ChangeUserName<'info> {
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"user-stats", user.key().as_ref()], bump = user_stats.bump)]
    pub user_stats: AccountLoader<'info, UserStats>,
}
```

I get an error:

> error[E0609]: no field `bump` on type
> `anchor_lang::prelude::AccountLoader<'_, UserStats>

Is that a limitation of Anchor or there is a way to fix that code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error indicates that you're trying to access the variable `bump` on the `user_stats` account inside the account struct. However because the account type is `AccountLoader` anchor specifically will not deserialise and load the account data into memory for you to access in the same way as the normal `Account<'info, >` syntax. This has to do with the fact it's a zero copy account. To access the bump variable you instead need to use the `load()` method on the account first:

```
bump = user_stats.load()?.bump
```

As noted in the other answer, you can also avoid this issue by using the `bump` keyword without assigning any value to it.

Comment: awesome, I din't know you can call functions inside attributes, seems like a right solution, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to specify anything beyond `bump` in the declaration. So there is no need for the `=user_stats.bump` as it uses the canonical bump by default.

Example:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ChangeUserName<'info> {
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut, seeds = [b"user-stats", user.key().as_ref()], bump)]
    pub user_stats: AccountLoader<'info, UserStats>,
}
```

Comment: I know that it works with the canonical bump, but I don't want Anchor to search for the PDA address wasting compute units